# How can I pipe something to less over ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, less

I am trying to configure a `mutt` binding to pipe an email into an `ssh` invocation to process the mail on a remote machine with a script that displays some output using `less`. However, this does not work, because `less` just gives me the entire output without paging.

Trying to narrow it down, what I am essentially trying to emulate is:

```
seq 1 100 | less
```

but with `less` running on the remote machine. (Because of my use case of calling the script in mutt, the `seq 1 100` part (representing the email) cannot run on the remote machine, nor can the `less` part (representing the script with less) run on the local machine.)

If I do:

```
seq 1 100 | ssh -t REMOTE_MACHINE less
```

I get the warning "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." and `less` displays the output directly without doing any paging.

If I do:

```
seq 1 100 | ssh -t -t REMOTE_MACHINE less
```

`less` fails with "Missing filename ("less --help" for help)", so I guess its input is lost.

I also tried adding `zsh -ic`, with no effect. **What is the right `ssh` invocation so that `less` on the remote host can read its standard input and do paging as usual?**

*Edit to try to answer Gilles' comment below:* The problem also occurs if the `less` invocation in the examples above is replaced by an actual script. If I create an executable file `script.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec less
```

and I put this in my home in both the local and remote machine, then the following works:

```
seq 1 100 | ~/script.sh
```

but the following does not (with `-t` or `-t -t` or neither):

```
seq 1 100 | ssh REMOTE_MACHINE less
```

Comment: `-t` ssh's option forces a tty allocation. The `|` (pipe) is creating a subshell, therefore the `-t` command can't extract a tty from it

Comment: How does the script read the data to process? If it reads from stdin, and it invokes less on the same stdin, then this can't work even without ssh involved. I suspect that the script doesn't work that way though. You need to tell us more about that script. Post a script that reproduces the problem with ssh, and that works when ssh isn't involved.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure I understood, but I edited the question to try to answer it.

Answer (score 5):

You can to pass the command as an argument and use `-t` to force pseudo terminal allocation.

For example if the `seq` command needs to run on the remote server:

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST -t 'seq 1 100 | less'
```

If the `seq` command needs to run on the local machine, so you could use a similar command using inline string `<<<` (of course the quoting becomes a little difficult):

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST -t "less <<< \"$(seq 1 100)\""
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works as-is for my use case (piping a message from mutt), where I can't easily arrange for mutt to run a convoluted ssh invocation like what you propose in your second example (and the first one is not OK because the email must come from the local machine). I guess I could do a wrapper script that passes stdin to the remote process in some fashion (with an inline string or a separate FIFO), but that's quite tedious. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @a3nm Then I would actually `scp` a file to the remote host which contains the result of the local command. A daemon on the remote host would process this file further.

Comment: Yeah I can certainly do this, but it's really ugly. I'm surprised that I cannot easily use ssh to run a remote command with terminal interaction and piped input in this way, so I'm still hoping for a better solution.